# Function : using the rule $y = ax+b$ find the missing information in the table

Tags: functions

Peter just got a job at a furniture manufacturing company. His boss offers him a base salary of $\$230$, and $\$15$ dollars for each piece of furniture he makes over the same period. 
[image]
Complete the following table of value that represents this situation

**My Work so far:**

- I know the rule is $y = 230 + 15x$
- $x =$ number of pieces of furniture made and $y =$ salary
- the rate of change is $15$
- I just don't know the easiest way to fill this table. Or do i solve for every $x$ the unknown $y$ and for every $y$ given the unknown $x$  using the rule?

Comment: You solve for every $x$ the unknown $y$ and for every $y$ the unknown $x$ using the rule.

Answer (score 1):

What your rule is telling you is that:
$$ \text{Total Salary}=\text{\$}230+\$15\times \text{Number of Pieces Made}$$

So you can use the values in the table to calculate the missing ones. Since for example the first one would be:
$$ \text{Total Salary}=\text{\$}230+\$15\times 3=\$ 295$$
Similarly for the second one it would be:
$$ \$305=\text{\$}230+\$15\times \text{Number of Pieces Made}  $$
so you can solve for the number of pieces made:
$$  \text{Number of Pieces Made}  =\frac{\$ 305-\$230}{\$15}=15 $$
Can you see how to continue with the rest?